# show $k! = m^\alpha$ is impossible

Tags: number-theory

I am not sure how to show that $$m^\alpha = k!$$ is impossible $\forall m,\alpha,k > 1$. I am supposed to use Bertrands theorem which states:  There exists atleast one prime in the open interval $(x, 2x)$ This is a homework question.

Comment: what do you know about the prime factorization of $m^\alpha,$ and what do you know about the prime factorization of $k!$

Comment: Will Jagy's question is your answer!

Comment: Perhaps you should specify that $\alpha$ (and $m$) are integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since $a>1$, every prime number appearing in the decomposition of $m^a$ has power greater than 1.

Let $k>2$. If $k$ is even,  there is a prime number $p$ between $k$ and $k/2$ and this prime number $p$ appears only once in $k!$, hence $k!\neq m^a$.

When $k$ is odd, there is a prime nubmer $p$ between $k-1$ and $(k-1)/2$  and this prime number $p$ appears only once in $k!$, hence $k!\neq m^a$.

This is a basic idea and you need to fill gaps.

Comment: I see the solution but what are the gaps I need to fill. Isnt your answer sufficient enough or is it missing something'

Comment: Maybe you need to write why that prime $p$ appears only once in the decomposition of $k!$.

Comment: Thats by bertrands theorem, correct? Consider $n! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \ldots \cdot n$. We know there exists a prime between $(\frac{n}{2}, n$ by Bertrands theorem. So $n/2 \leq p \leq n$. so then by definition of the factorial, p can only appear once

Comment: Yes, you are right. But a slight problem is that when $k=4$, you might take $p=2$. In this case, $p$ appears more than once.

Comment: but its an open interval, so if $k = 4$ then there is some prime between $(2, 4)$ which is 3.

Comment: Ok, I thought it is closed interval. In that case it is fine.

Comment: could you discuss the case where its closed? just for personal satisfaction.